# How to have list of incoming and outgoing tx given an address?

Tags: monerod, transaction-data, ring-signatures, cryptography, javascript

I have my **full monero node** and I'm trying to extrapolate from it, all the **tx** (incoming and outgoing) involving my address. Right now I'm using the **`monerojs`** library and scanning the blocks, the data I'll need in theory will be:

```
 inputs: [ [MoneroOutput], [MoneroOutput] ],
 outputs: [ [MoneroOutput], [MoneroOutput] ],
```

I've gotten to the point of checking out these items:

```
MoneroOutput {
    state: {
      amount: [BigInteger],
      keyImage: [MoneroKeyImage],
      ringOutputIndices: [Array],
      tx: [MoneroTx]
    }
  }
```

ringOutputIndices should be the object where the **Ring Signatures** are applied. I would like to know if there are any ways to be able to trace my tx, obviously having my private keys available.

Are there any code examples or documentation to consult for this purpose?

Comment: Have you not seen the docs? https://github.com/monero-ecosystem/monero-javascript/blob/master/docs/developer_guide/query_data_model.md

Comment: i have a problem with this, if you can see my last comment on this thread: https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/13981/problem-signing-transactions-with-monerojs